# Include CodeIgniter Page in a standard PHP Page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm planning on writing a CMS using CodeIgniter that will give the user a small bit of code to add to their standard php page that will include certain CMS elements like a news feed. Their website files will be in the root. If it was possible to do it with an include it would look something like this:

```
<?php include('news-feed/list/15'); ?>
```

Whats the best way to do this? I don't want the user to have to page a large amount of code in their files. Could I also do this multiple times on a page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "action/method/params";
require_once "pathto/index.php";
```

This should do the trick